# Get the addition of a property in an array of objects with repeated IDs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have and array of objects, something like that:

```
myArr = [{id: 1, x:100, y:200},{id:1, x:50, y:25},{id:2, x:60, y:80},{id:2, x:50, y:100},{id:2, x:50, y:60}]
```

What I want is to make an array like that:

```
wantedArray = [{id: 1, x: 150, y: 225}, {id:2, x: 160, 240}]
```

Where make the addition of each x, y if "id" is the same. Thanks!

Comment: What have you attempted?

Comment: Nothing, i can't figure out how to do this:(

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: What do you want is not valid json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to reduce Object.values

This works too and saves a casting

```js
const myArr = [{id: 1, x:100, y:200},{id:1, x:50, y:25},{id:2, x:60, y:80},{id:2, x:50, y:100},{id:2, x:50, y:60}]

const sum = myArr.reduce((acc,cur) => {
  const obj = acc.find(({id}) => id===cur.id);
  if (obj) { obj.x+=cur.x; obj.y+=cur.y }
  else acc.push(cur)
  return acc;
},[]);
console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce` to sum on property `x` and `y` for each unique `id` in an object accumulator.

```js
const myArr = [{id: 1, x:100, y:200},{id:1, x:50, y:25},{id:2, x:60, y:80},{id:2, x:50, y:100},{id:2, x:50, y:60}],
      result = Object.values(myArr.reduce((r, {id, x, y}) => {
        r[id] = r[id] || {id, x: 0, y: 0};
        r[id].x += x;
        r[id].y += y;
        return r;
      },{}));
console.log(result);
```